# I don't know how to verify if a parameter exists in the funcion or procedure

Tags: plsql

Design a table named "customs agencies" with the following fields: name, address, patent number, id_ customs agent. Where customs agent is another table with name and seniority.

Create a function or procedure that allows inserting new agencies and being able to edit an agency giving the ID of the customs agency.

I don't know how to do this: If id exists in parameter we do an update, else we insert new agencies.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose parameter's name is `PAR_ID`; then you'd

```
create or replace procedure p_agency (par_id in agency.id%type,
                                      par_name in agency.name%type
                                     )
is
begin
  if par_id is null then
     insert into agency (id, name) values (par_id, par_name);
  else
     update agency set name = par_name
       where id = par_id;
  end if;
end;
```

If you wonder where are other columns - well, I'll leave that piece of homework to you.

Comment: Are you able to chat or something?, i am having problems with the procedure.